# Create an asset in Earth Engine from GCP bucket

Tags: shapefile, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I would like to upload a shapefile that I have on a GCP bucket to Earth Engine.
I know that I could use something like `earthengine upload image --asset_id=users/username/asset_id gs://bucket/image.tif` but for my project I can't use command line and need to use only the code editor.
I think that I can achieve what I want using `ee.data.startTableIngestion()` but I can't figure out how to use this function.
Can someone help me out?

I tried this without success:

```
var taskid = ee.data.newTaskId(1);

var assetid = 'projects/earthengine-legacy/assets/projects/myproject/my_new_asset'

var params = {
  'name': assetid,
  'sources': [{"uris":["gs://mybucket/myshapefile.shp"],"charset":"UTF-8"}]
};
ee.data.startTableIngestion(taskid[0], params)
```

I have this error: Name "projects/earthengine-public/assets/undefined" is invalid. The portion of the Asset name following "projects/*/assets/" must have at least 3 segments and at most 10 segments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer has been provided here: https://groups.google.com/g/google-earth-engine-developers/c/i8zEo1_hPlM

Here is the solution:

```
var taskid = ee.data.newTaskId(1);

var assetid = 'projects/myproject/assets/newassetname';
var asset_url = 'gs://mybucket/myshapefile.shp';

var params = {
  'id': assetid,
  'sources': [{"primaryPath":asset_url,"charset":"UTF-8"}]
};

ee.data.startTableIngestion(taskid[0], params)
```